# Count by row on based on more than one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data shaped like the following in excel:

```
A       B  C  D
"foo"   5  3  1
"foo"   2  4  5
"foo"   5  5  5
"bar"   1  2  3
"bar"   4  5  7
```

I want to know how many rows contain "foo" in column A and 5 in either one of column B, C or D.

In other words, I want the following formula `=COUNTIFS(A1:A5;"foo";B1:B5;5;C1:C5;5;D1:D5;5)`, but with the B, C and D ranges `or`'ed together instead of `and`'ed. Is there a simple way to do this with an excel formula?

Comment: try [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try,

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="foo")*SIGN((B1:B5=5)+(C1:C5=5)+(D1:D5=5)))`

Comment: I was trying to answer with a clever array formula, but this is nice!

Comment: This is really nice formula

Answer (score 0):

If we can use a extra column then also we can achieve this task

```
A   B   C   D   E
foo 5   0   1   =COUNTIF(B2:D2,5)(1)
foo 2   5   5   =COUNTIF(B3:D3,5)(2)
foo 5   5   5   =COUNTIF(B4:D4,5)(3)
bar 1   5   3   =COUNTIF(B5:D5,5)(1)
foo 4   0   7   =COUNTIF(B6:D6,5)(0)
```

Then, we can use countifs

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"foo",E:E,">0") = 3
```